# How can I capture the video of selenium automation test on failure with data driven UI automation framework using pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest, data-driven-tests, conftest

Here, I will be running my selenium automation test with pytest framework and using data driven approach. that means there is only function in testcase file.

Note: service_name is a variable which is containing service_name from data file and and it is getting service_name one by one from data file and that you can consider one service_name is equal to one testcase.

e.g:

```
def test_data(setup, service_name):
    service_data = utils.get_data_for_service(service_name)
    if service_data is True:
       print("data is present for service_name", service_name)
    else:
       print("No data found for service_name", service_name)
```

Now, please help me to capture video for each service_name testcase on test failure.
Thanks in advance.